# Is there any way to show widget it two different tabs?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I have QTabWidget, and layout with some widgets and sub layouts that I want to show in this QTabWidget tabs. what I want to do is to add this layout to the first tab (as default), and if the user moves to the next tab, I want to show the exact same layout, and to add some widgets near it. 
this is the layout that I am talking about:

```
    self.right_tab_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.right_tab_widget = QWidget()
    self.right_tab_title_label = QLabel("Select full files path:")
    self.simoderev_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.simoderev_widget = QWidget()
    self.simoderev_checkbox = QCheckBox("use simoderev as base: ")
    self.simoderev_combobox = QComboBox()
    self.paths_label = QLabel("paths:")

    self.right_tab_widget.setLayout(self.right_tab_layout)

    self.simoderev_widget.setLayout(self.simoderev_layout)
    self.simoderev_widget.setMaximumWidth(250)

    self.simoderev_layout.addWidget(self.simoderev_checkbox)
    self.simoderev_layout.addWidget(self.simoderev_combobox)
    self.simoderev_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

    self.right_tab_layout.addWidget(self.right_tab_title_label)
    self.right_tab_layout.addWidget(self.simoderev_widget)
    self.right_tab_layout.addWidget(self.paths_label)
```

is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the widgets in the tabs to **look** the same, you should create a custom Widget class and put an instance of that class in each tab.

Your custom widget could look like:

```
class CustomWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.title_label = QtGui.QLabel("Select full files path:")
        self.simoderev_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        simoderev_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.simoderev_widget)
        self.simoderev_checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox("use simoderev as base: ")
        self.simoderev_combobox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.simoderev_widget.setMaximumWidth(250)
        simoderev_layout.addWidget(self.simoderev_checkbox)
        simoderev_layout.addWidget(self.simoderev_combobox)
        simoderev_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.paths_label = QtGui.QLabel("paths:")
        layout.addWidget(self.title_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.simoderev_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.paths_label)
```

If you want them to **be** the same, here's a hacky solution. You should connect the `currentChanged` signal of your tabwidget to a slot that will move your custom widget from one tab to the other.

```
class MyTabWidget(QtGui.QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyTabWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.subwidget = CustomWidget(self)

        self.left_tab_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.leftLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.left_tab_widget)
        self.leftLayout.addWidget(self.subwidget)

        self.right_tab_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.rightLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.right_tab_widget)
        label = QtGui.QLabel("Some additional data", self.right_tab_widget)
        self.rightLayout.addWidget(label)

        self.addTab(self.left_tab_widget, "Left Tab")
        self.addTab(self.right_tab_widget, "Right Tab")

        self.currentChanged.connect(self.onCurrentChanged)

    def onCurrentChanged(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            self.leftLayout.addWidget(self.subwidget)
        else:
            self.rightLayout.addWidget(self.subwidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyTabWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: super() is used to call the base class `__init__`. You could've replaced `super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)` with `QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)`